# one or [the] other in American and British English

Tags: definite-articles, dialectal

I'm wondering whether the definite article should be placed before "other" in the following sentence, and whether there is dialectal variation in this regard:

> You should ask one or [the] other of your grandparents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version without the article seems to be preferred in British English while being strongly disfavored in American English. The version with the article is common in both varieties of English.

Having said that, depending on the precise context, the two versions may mean different things.

If the intended meaning is that you should ask one out of **more than two** grandparents, then there should be no *the.* However, I agree with user Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment, below, that in  American English, *one or another* would be much more likely in that case.

If there are **just two** grandparents you could ask, then, in principle, either is acceptable. However, dropping the article seems to actually be preferred in British English, while in American English retaining the article is strongly preferred, and dropping it may sound outdated.

**Discussion**

**General dictionaries**

*Merriam-Webster* only has an entry for *one or **the** other*, which it defines as *one of **two** persons or things but not the other* [(here)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one%20or%20other).

The *Oxford English Dictionary (OED)* mentions both phrases in its entry for *one*. So we find the following:

> 9.a. Used in antithesis to *another, other, others.* ***one and another:*** more than one, two or more in succession. ***one or other of:*** one of.

A sample of usage:

> The metallic ores are usually embedded in **one or other** of these minerals.

The *OED* also mentions an obsolete usage of *one or other,* with the meaning *altogether; one way or another; in all respects.* Sample usage (from 1796): *Indiana has **one or other** the prettiest face I ever saw.*

Finally, the *OED* notes that *one* is used as *short for ‘one or the other’,* with a remark *US Regional*. A sample sentence: *The driver had to stop or run me over, **one**.*

None of the sources I consulted explicitly mention regional variation, though of course that doesn't necessarily mean there isn't one. For what it's worth, [*Garner's Modern American Usage*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195161912) doesn't have an entry for either; it does **use** *one or **the** other* twice in the text.

**Corpora of English**

All things being equal, a larger corpus will inevitably have more hits. Therefore what I will be giving is the *ratio* of the number of hits to the total number of words in the corpus, a quantity I will call the ***scaled*** number of hits.

**Corpus of Contemporary American English** (COCA)
        scaled numbers of hits (×10 <sup>- 7</sup>):
                *one or other*           1
                *one or another*      9
                *one or the other*   18

**British National Corpus** (BNC)
        scaled numbers of hits (×10 <sup>- 7</sup>):
                *one or other*        39
                *one or another*      6
                *one or the other*   15

(The raw numbers of hits were, respectively,  60, 505, and 1034 in COCA, which has a total of [560 million](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) words, and 390, 64, and 150 in BNC, which has a total of [100 million](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) words.)

These results suggest that, in American English, *one or other* is largely disfavored: *one or another* is 9 times more frequent, and *one or the other* 18 times. In contrast, in British English, *one or other* is actually *preferred*, being 6 times more frequent than *one or another* and 2.6 times more frequent than *one or the other*.

**Comprehensive grammars**

Both [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) and [ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0582517346) freely use both *one or other* and *one or the other,* and they use the former even when there are just two alternatives. CGEL in particular uses *one or other* a lot, both in the body of the text and in the exaples. On the other hand, [Longman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0582237254) doesn't use *one or other* at all, and only has three occurences of *one or the other.*

It should be noted that CGEL mentions (p. 1330) that *one or other* can also be used as a fixed phrase, which functions as a determiner meaning "either/any".

**Examples of usage from google books**

As far as *one or other*, consider the following examples of usage:

> These different forms which warfare takes according as **one or other** of the **three** arms preponderates… [(source)](https://clausewitz.com/readings/OnWar1873/BK5ch04.html)
>   
>   I have also been very successful with solutions of ferric salts which are precipitated by ammonia either alone or with **one or other** of the above salts and acids. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=1HZGAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22one%20or%20other%22&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=%22one%20or%20other%22&f=false)

In these cases, it is clear that *other* refers to elements of a set that has more than two members.

However, there are also examples like this, where *one or other* is clearly used to refer to members of a set of just two things:

> … **two separate windings** arranged within said hollow core and surrounding the said cores, two connected movable iron plates arranged at the opposite ends of said case and core, a holder for said case, two insulated fixed switch contacts connected each to one end of **one or other** of said **windings**… [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=OFRGAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22each%20to%20one%20end%20of%20one%20or%20other%22&pg=PA2032#v=onepage&q=%22each%20to%20one%20end%20of%20one%20or%20other%22&f=false)

From searching through google books, however, one gets the impression that *one or other* was more likely to be used in times past. Google Ngram is consistent with that impression:

[image]

Comment: I’d say dropping the article sounds more than just a bit old-timey nowadays. To me it’s completely archaic. I wouldn’t even use it for groups of more than three options – I’d use _one or another_ instead. According to the answers to [this old question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/63510), _one or other_ is more common in BrE than in AmE, so this is apparently a case where I side with the Americans.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for that comment! I looked at COCA and BNC, and updated my answer.

Comment: Traditionally, if there are 3 objects, **one** is the largest and **another** ("plural form", versus the dual **the other**) is the smallest.